# AttachConsole and 64 bit application

Tags: delphi, winapi

The WinAPI function `AttachConsole` always returns true when the program is compiled as 64-bit.

First of all, I've declared the function as following:

```
function AttachConsole(dwProcessId: DWORD): Bool; stdcall; external KERNEL32 name 'AttachConsole';
```

Then I call my function:

```
if AttachConsole(DWORD(-1)) then
   ....
```

This works fine when compiled as a 32-bit application, but when compiled as 64-bit it always returns true.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) doesn't mention doing something special for a 64-bit application.

**How to reproduce**:

1. Create a new VCL Application
2. Set Target platform to Win64
3. Edit the DPR file to look like this:

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.Types,
  WinApi.windows,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

function AttachConsole(dwProcessId: DWORD): Bool; stdcall; external KERNEL32 name 'AttachConsole';


begin
  if AttachConsole(DWORD(-1)) then
  begin
    writeLN('Hello world');
    Exit;
  end;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

When running under Win64, `AttachConsole` retruns true even when run from Explorer.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, the 64-bit compiler does something weird with `DWORD(-1)` - have you tried it with `$FFFFFFFF`?

Comment: Yes same result: False positive.

Comment: more useful will be if you attach binary code instead src

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) link, `dwProcessId [in]` can take two types of values - either a PID of the target process or the special argument :

> **ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS** (DWORD)-1
>
> Use the console of the parent of the current process.

Here you are using the value `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS`.

In the case of a 64-bit debug, it appears that the IDE is creating a console for the 64-bit debugger, which hosts the debugged application as a child, and so electing to attach to the parent console succeeds.

For a 32-bit debug session the application is spawned as a child of the IDE.  We can guess that this is because the IDE itself is a 32-bit application and can hook into the 32-bit process directly while the 64-bit application must be attached to a 64-bit debugger.

Using process explorer we can see the difference in the process hierarchy when launching the process for debugging within the IDE :

[image]

[image]

Here we can see the 64-bit process is hosted as a child in the debugger kernel while the 32-bit process is not.

Running the (64-bit) application outside of the debugger produces the expected result where `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` fails.

Comment: Sorry my bad. My question wasn't clear. You should use a GUI program. I've updated the question.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt I've updated the answer.  I think this is what is going on.

Comment: Ok so in Short: It won't work under 64 bit when running from the debugger

Comment: @JensBorrisholt I suppose, although it's not clear what "work" means - in a 64-bit debug there will always be a parent console available to attach to.  If you need to distinguish this particular console from other potentially present parent consoles then that may be possible, of course.